# how can I do "twoDataBinding" with formControlName? similar with ng Model

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I'm setting a model with form, but I have a problem to set a "MyModel" with a form

This is for the purpose of optimizing the handling of the forms

```
public myModel = new MyModel();
```

```
this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: new FormControl({
        value: this.myModel.firstName,
        disabled: false
      }),
      middleName: new FormControl({
        value: this.myModel.middleName,
        disabled: false
      }),
      lastName: new FormControl({
        value: this.myModel.lastName,
        disabled: false
      }),
      age: new FormControl({
        value: this.myModel.age,
        disabled: false
      })
    });
```

when I submit a "submit" with a button, that shows me the "this.myForm" with the elements that I added in the form
but it seems that I would not be establishing a connection as a "TwoDataBinding"
I also do not want to do this code since I see it very redundant

also

when it comes to many forms and even worse if you decide to change or refactor the attributes of that object

```
    this.myModel.firstName = this.myForm.controls['firstName'].value;
    this.myModel.lastName = this.myForm.controls['lastName'].value;
    this.myModel.middleName = this.myForm.controls['middleName'].value;
    this.myModel.age = this.myForm.controls['age'].value;
```

You can see the complete code here:https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-model-hammer 
of a form model, if you want to make changes makes a FORK to share, thanks:

[also for the purpose of avoiding this alert in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPmIu.png)

Comment: Unable to understand, What do you want actually!

Comment: I think the code in stackblitz, will make you understand better

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use 2-way binding, you should use [template-driven forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms#template-driven-forms) instead. It allows you to use `ngModel` to create two-way data bindings for reading and writing input-control values.

The principles of [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#introduction-to-reactive-forms) follows the 'one-way' rule, whereby you follow an immutable method of managing the state of your forms, such that there is greater separation of concern between your template and component logic. You can read more about the advantages of reactive forms on the above link.

If you think reactive forms is not what you want, you should revert to using template driven forms, as stated on the first paragraph.

One thing to take note, you should not use ngModel with reactive forms, as this will defeat the purpose of immutability.

However, if you are planning to stick to using reactive forms, you can simplify your code by doing this instead:

1) Initialising and declaring your reactive forms.

```
this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  firstName: [{value: this.myModel.firstName, disabled: true}],
  middleName: [this.myModel.middleName],
  lastName: [this.myModel.Name],
  age: [this.myModel.age],
});
```

2) Get reactive form data:

```
// since the properties of myModel and myForm FormControl names are the same
this.myModel = {...this.myForm.value};
```

3) Update reactive form data:

```
this.myForm.patchValue(this.myModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should stop using ngModel with Reactive forms as it is deprecated now .
You can simplify the code like below :

```
this.myModel.firstName= 'FIRST NAME';
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName:[{
        value: this.myModel ? this.myModel.firstName : '',
        disabled: false
      }],
      middleName: [{
        value: this.myModel ? this.myModel.middleName : '',
        disabled: false
      }],
      lastName: [{
        value: this.myModel ? this.myModel.lastName : '',
        disabled: false
      }],
      age:[{
        value: this.myModel ? this.myModel.age : '',
        disabled: false
      }]
    });
```

Listen to `(ngOnSubmit)` event and write a function to save the form values .
This can be achieved in the below way :

```
  save(myForm : any){
    let form = myForm as MyModel;
    console.log(form);
    form.otherProperties = 'nothing';
  }
```

Or :

```
  save(myForm : MyModel){
    let form = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myForm)); //for copy
    console.log(form);
    form.otherProperties = 'nothing';
    console.log( 'added a new property', form);
  }
```

And in your html :

```
<div>
  <form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)='save(myForm.value)'>
    <label>
      <span>
        Fisrt name:
      </span>
      <input type="text" formControlName="firstName">
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>
        Middle name
      </span>
      <input type="text" formControlName="middleName">
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>
        Last name
      </span>
      <input type="text" formControlName="lastName">
    </label>
    <label>
      <span> Age: </span>
      <input type="number" formControlName="age">
    </label>
    <div style="display: block">
      <button (click)="onShowModel()">
        show model
      </button>
    </div>

    <div style="display: block">
      <button>
        set model from form
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div>
  <p class="red"> from model : </p>
  <span class="red"> Model: {{myModel | json}}  {{nothing}}</span>

</div>

<div>
  <p class="blue"> from form, binding model : </p>
  <span class="blue"> Model: {{myForm.value | json}}</span>
</div>
```

I have also forked your example : [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-faeboy)